# Need Help Windows 10 ntoskrnl.exe!<Symbols disabled> is using 20% ofusage

Tags: windows, cpu, cpu-usage

I tried everything I can find here and many other sites using Google in order to solve this but no luck.

I used WPT and this is what I got.

Processes that constantly uses the CPU:

[image]

I just installed Windows with all software and drivers.

Comment: configure the debug symbols in WPA correctly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh162982.aspx and load them

Comment: any upate? Have you loaded the symbols? Do you see more details?

Comment: I suppose it's too late to ask... My symbols aren't loading either (well they load, but I just get Symbols Disabled on each line).

Comment: Same! Need help on this!

Answer (score 1):

As the comments recommended, I solved this by loading the windows symbol.

● If you have already downloaded the symbols, go to `Trace>Configure Symbol Paths` and make sure the path is right. Because I didn't download the symbols to the default path, I had to delete the default path and add this one:

```
srv*C:\symcache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Then go to `Trace>Load Symbols` and wait for the loading (it can take a while...).

To speed up the process, you can right-click on the process you wan to explore and select `Filter to selection` so that only the symbols needed for that process are loaded.

● If you haven't downloaded the symbol yet, you can directly click on `Trace>Load Symbols`, and the symbols will be downloaded to the default path. This will really take a while because first the symbol will be downloaded and then they will be loaded into the program.