# ntoskrnl.exe is causing high CPU usage, and I can't debug it due to <Symbols disabled> in WPA

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu, performance, cpu-usage

I've tried following the top solution here [Troubleshoot High CPU usage by the "System" process](https://superuser.com/questions/527401/troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-by-the-system-process). It seems quite a few people have had this same ntoskrnl.exe nonstop CPU usage problem. However, as you can see, no matter how many ntoskrnl.exe trees I open it's just more and more of the same. I think I have the same issue as the asker in this question [Need Help Windows 10 ntoskrnl.exe!<Symbols disabled> is using 20% ofusage](https://superuser.com/questions/1115298/need-help-windows-10-ntoskrnl-exesymbols-disabled-is-using-20-ofusage?rq=1). But that one was left unsolved. How do I debug the issue here? And how can I get Symbols to not be disabled, presumably so I can further investigate the issue?

My laptop fan is blowing super loud almost nonstop so I have to either keep it shut off all the time or just listen to it working itself to death 24/7.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Try the suggestions in this article below:

https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/system-ntoskrnl-exe-high-memory-or-cpu-usage-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking into [Need Help Windows 10 ntoskrnl.exe!<Symbols disabled> is using 20% ofusage](https://superuser.com/questions/1115298/need-help-windows-10-ntoskrnl-exesymbols-disabled-is-using-20-ofusage?rq=1).

Like you, I believe, I was confused and not sure about what they meant by loading the Symbols.

It turns out it is in a WPA menu. All you need to do (that's what I did) is to go to "Trace" and click "Load Symbols".

[Image: Trace -> Load Symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZvX9.png)

That's it. Once you've done that you should get rid of '<Symbols disabled>' and be able to further debug your issue.